# Can't update system due to mystery package and lack of instructions

Tags: package-management, solaris, upgrade

I'm having trouble updating all packages on Solaris 11.3. I use the system for testing software. I'm not a Solaris admin or a Solaris user.

When attempting to update the system I'm encountering the following (this used to work):

```
$ sudo pkg update
Password:
------------------------------------------------------------
Package: pkg://solaris/release/evaluation@1.0,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.115.0:20170111T175931Z
License: evaluation

This software has been made available for evaluation purposes only.
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/foss-evaluation-program-2586275.html for further information.        

            Packages to remove:   1
           Packages to install:   3
            Packages to update:   2
            Services to change:   1
       Create boot environment:  No
Create backup boot environment: Yes

pkg: The following packages require their licenses to be accepted before they can be installed or updated:
----------------------------------------
Package: pkg://solaris/release/evaluation@1.0,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.115.0:20170111T175931Z

License: evaluation
  License requires acceptance.

To indicate that you agree to and accept the terms of the licenses of the packages listed above, use the --accept option.  To display all of the related licenses, use the --licenses option.
```

I'm not sure what the message is talking about. I accepted the adminstrivia fodder when I installed the system last year. I did not install a package called ***pkg://solaris/release/evaluation***, and I'm not sure where it came from. However, I gave it its due diligence, which did not work:

```
$ sudo pkg --accept update
pkg: illegal global option -- accept
Try `pkg --help or -?' for more information.
```

I visited the URL cited in the message, but it does not tell me what needs to be done. The page describe an oracle program. Apparently, what needs to be done is top secret or above.

What needs to be done to update this system?

More humorously, how did Oracle manage to break a simple process that worked for years?

Answer (score 2):

Read the man page. It is pretty clear what is the error:

```
/usr/bin/pkg update [-fnvq] [-g path_or_uri ...]
    [--accept] [--licenses] [--no-index] [--no-refresh] [--no-be-activate]
    [--no-backup-be | --require-backup-be] [--backup-be-name name]
    [--deny-new-be | --require-new-be] [--be-name name]
    [--reject pkg_fmri_pattern ...] [pkg_fmri_pattern ...]
```

`pkg update --accept` and not `pkg --accept update.`

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to remove `pkg://solaris/release/evaluation`? If its going to cause chronic problems, then there is no reason to leave it on the system.

Comment: It depends if you've installed any software from the [FOSS Evaluation packages for Solaris](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/foss-evaluation-program-2586275.html) -- if not, you should be able to simply `pkg uninstall pkg://solaris/release/evaluation` - you can always try and see if that warns anything else requires it.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the following to update the package list:

```
pkg update --accept
```

then the following to install a package (in this example Samba):

```
pkg install --accept samba
```

Make sure you keep the exact order of the parameters otherwise you get errors.